# How to type "Ґ" on Ubuntu Ukrainian keyboard layout?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have a standard Ukrainian keyboard layout on Ubuntu. How to type Ґ on it?

Comment: Do you have the key between Left Shift and z(я)?

Comment: @choroba, no I do not have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I just have to push that button with slashes and not hold alt or any other buttons. Who would know.

[image]